# Angular : How to make undo on canvas drawing?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, canvas

I'm creating some drawing tool which is required in my current project, as per my requirement the drawing works fine, but I'm trying to create the UNDO option, and it's not working properly.

Once the undo button clicks I need to remove the last drawn line only.

Refer the code here

```
<div style="position : relative">
  <canvas class="roiCanvas" id="canvas" #roiCanvas></canvas>

  <button (click)="clear()">Clear</button>
  <button (click)="undo()">Undo</button>
</div>
```

Angular Code  for undo:

```
 drawPaths() {
    // delete everything
    this.cx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvasWidth, this.canvasHeight);
    // draw all the paths in the paths array
    this.lineTo.forEach((path: any) => {
      this.cx.beginPath();
      var last = this.lineTo[this.lineTo.length - 1];
      this.cx.moveTo(last.x, last.y);
      for (let i = 1; i < path.length; i++) {
        this.drawChart(path[i].x, path[i].y);
        this.cx.lineTo(path[i].x, path[i].y);
      }
      this.cx.strokeStyle = '#0652DD';
      this.cx.stroke();
    });
  }
  undo() {
    this.lineTo.splice(-1, 1);
    console.log(this.lineTo);
    this.drawPaths();
  }
```

[image]
Please check the below stackblitz codebase.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kdc7dp?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: just for good measure, often the command pattern can be used for do and undo operations - perhaps a good read: https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your `drawPaths()` function is using the last position, which does not work when this is removed:

`var last = this.lineTo[this.lineTo.length - 1];`

So i re-wrote the undo function to just draw the lines from start to finish, and this now works.

See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kdc7dp?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
undo() {
  this.lineTo.splice(-1, 1);
  
  this.cx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvasWidth, this.canvasHeight);

  this.lineTo.forEach((path: any, i: any) => {

    this.cx.beginPath();

    this.drawChart(path.x, path.y);

    if(this.lineTo.length > i+1) {
      this.cx.lineTo(this.lineTo[i+1].x, this.lineTo[i+1].y);
    }

    this.cx.strokeStyle = '#0652DD';
    this.cx.stroke();
  });
}
```

I'll leave it to you to dedupe the code and make it nice ;)